# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).steps is not a function error within .net Core application

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, jquery-steps

I am receiving this error when trying to run a simple jquery.steps demo in my .Net Core site:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).steps is not a function
```

Here is my code for the particular page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>

<div id="example-basic">
    <h3>Keyboard</h3>
    <section>
        <p>Try the keyboard navigation by clicking arrow left or right!</p>
    </section>
    <h3>Effects</h3>
    <section>
        <p>Wonderful transition effects.</p>
    </section>
    <h3>Pager</h3>
    <section>
        <p>The next and previous buttons help you to navigate through your content.</p>
    </section>
</div>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery.steps/build/jquery.steps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#example-basic").steps({
            headerTag: "h3",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            autoFocus: true
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a 304 response when checking the jquery.steps.js file within chrome.

It doesn't appear that the steps call is being found in the library, any ideas?

Comment: The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Comment: Are you getting a 404 for that script?

Comment: `~/lib`   the `~` doesn't look like a normal url to me.

Comment: The page does display, none of the jquery.steps functionality is there though, just the <h3> and <p> tags

Comment: @Xufox Ah apologies for the misunderstanding, yes the jquery.steps.js file is found when looking at the network tab for the page. It has a 304 status.

Comment: Always the first step when the js doesn't do what you expect - clear cache and hard reload.